# How do you awake all aircraft on a tile?

Tags: civilization-5

It is fairly tedious to awake many aircraft on a tile. I'm wondering if there is a shortcut available to wake aircraft in a city, instead of clicking on each, one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such shortcut available right now.

Expect one to pop up soon once the modders get full access to the game.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to wake up aircraft on the same tile by clicking on the tile that has the aircraft, hitting the <kbd>F</kbd> key to wake them and then clicking on the hex again which causes the next aircraft to come to focus. If another unit comes to focus, it is either a case or keep clicking or that I have reached full cycle of the unit stack.

Once the aircraft are awake, they will come to life before the end of the turn.

Click, <kbd>F</kbd>, Click, <kbd>F</kbd>, Click, <kbd>F</kbd> etc is my routine.